# Translation on a Dashboard

Tags: internationalisation

We are in the middle of a i18n process for a product.
On a dashboard we have a Widget with news in the German language.
Now we also offer our dashboard in English.
Problem is: the news are a RSS Feed that we have no control of. The news are only available in German. What can I do? Should I leave the German news there inside the widget when the person switches to English? Or should I remove the News / give the information that the news are not available in english? Any other options?

Comment: Is it not possible to switch RSS feeds when you switch the language?

Comment: Sadly no. There is only 1 source of the RSS feed and its german.

Comment: A new source? Are you after German news in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 types of language users:

1. Doesn't speak german and therefor switches to english.
2. User knows german but prefers english for a UI.
3. Is german, prefers german.

**Number 3** isn't the problem.

**Number 1** doesn't have any use for the newsfeed at all and therefor probably doesnt want to have something in his view that he can't understand anyway.

**Number 2** does want to read it sometimes. I can imagine it's a small percentage of the users though.

---

**Option A)**

It's hard to distinguish between user 1 and 2, therefor having the user in control to hide/display it could be a good option. You could explain the user in a small tooltip / message that the feed is not available in his language and ask if he wants to hide it.

---

**Option B)**

If the percentage of number 2 users is really low I would just hide it. If something is available for me but I can't benefit/use it why show it? Plus I wouldn't want to give the user the feeling that something is 'incomplete'. I can't speak Chinese so for me it wouldn't make sense to display a feed in Chinese on my dashboard. A user can't tell if something is not even there but a user can tell if something is "not working".

---

Depending how important you think the feed information is I would go for option A or B. I'm leaning towards option B though

Comment: I would prefer Option A. I would always give option to customize the dashboard, e.g hide/show widgets or select only the widgets the user need.

Comment: Usually I would prefer option A as well, but thats in scenarios where its really unpredictable wether a feature is being used yes or no. I.e. some users think its useful, some do not. The more a feature leans towards the 'not usefull', the higher the chance I would disable it completely. This could be a scenario like that

Comment: However, removing the widget completely could give the user the impression of an incomplete user interface. So you should at least inform why something is missing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I had the same thoughts and I didn’t want to remove the widget just because the user switches the language. I think the tooltip and the option to hide it sounds best.